# Which channel protocol should I use to broadcast the message between parties?

Tags: public-key, elliptic-curves, dsa, cryptocurrency, threshold-cryptography

I am building the Threshold Signature Scheme (TSS) based wallet. I would like to run the each party's node separately with different host. And these nodes should be able to send the messages through the secured and authenticated channel to the other partie's nodes. So what channel protocol is prefered to used. Can i use the rabbitMQ?